# signal strength *send* by my phone

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, calls, microphone

When I get a call, I often can hear the other side just fine, but they don't hear me. This happens so often that I wonder if the problem could be my phone's **sending** signal strength. (There are tons of apps showing the received signal strength, but this is not my point.)

- Is there a way to measure or configure this?
- Is this a possible explanation at all?

Edit: should have added that the call is often dropped some seconds after I become inaudible. I hear the other side crisp and clear complaining about me not audible and then it drops.

Further I discovered the Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> SUBS Status (my translations from German) where I see that the connection is difficult in these situations (UMTS at -95dbm to -103dbm).

The model I am envisaging is that the receive (from cell) and send channels (to cell) are slightly asymmetric, due to walls, buildings and other obstacles, such that the phone software underestimates the necessary sending power by a few percent.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to measure or Comfigure *send* signal strength. If the problem is same irrespective of your location, work, home, anywhere, it is more likely an hardware Issue with the device

Comment: Also check out the problem is same if you use speaker phone. If it isn't it is likely mic issue

Comment: Yep, a hardware problem is what I am suspecting, so I hoped for some way to check what is actually going on. In fact it is not always a problem, only in certain locations, which is why I suspect the send signal strength is just, say, 20% to low, so that under good conditions everything is fine.

Comment: If the call is not dropped, that confirms there is enough sending signal strength.

Answer (score 1):

Sending strength:  Modern digital cellphones are set to utilize the minimum power to maintain a connection.  So the fact that the connection isn't dropping completely tells you that you have sufficient RF signal strength to make and receive calls.

Talk Volume:  As for them telling you that your voice is not loud enough I would suspect the microphone itself.  Like maybe pocket lint got into it or it got poked with something.

If it is an older phone it is possible that some part has failed or is in the process of fading.

In order to properly diagnose this, I would want to know 1) Did this start suddenly, or has it been a gradual change?  2) Can you send texts?  (They require sending power to connect), and 3) How has the phone been treated?  Has it been dropped or anything like that?

With the little information you provided I would look closely at the phone itself.

And you can rest assured you are getting enough sending power.  Digital is not like old phones where it can connect but you have to yell because of bad amplifiers in the central office.  With digital, you can either connect or not, period.  If the circuitry canperform their internal handshakes that maintain the connection then you are fine.  If the error rate goes up, your phone will automatically raise its signal strength until the celll network is happy enough to maintain the connection.

That is enough diagnosis to determine your signal strength is sufficient.

Comment: "rest assured you are getting enough sending power" is exactly what I would like to verify :-) No, it did not start suddenly, its on and off, so  sometimes can send text, sometime it lingers until I move around when it then suddenly is send. The phone is fairly new and treated the best way I can think of. See edits too.

Comment: The device can't measure the power it sending, that is done on the receiving side or with a specialized meter (which costs dozens of times more than your phone). Your low volume issue is hardware (mic) or codec problem... Low Tx power would not change your volume, that would be an analog issue and all modern phones transmit and receive voice as 1's and 0's, if there wasn't enough power and digits were getting lost, the call would choppy/broken or drop, but the volume would not change.

Comment: @acejavelin is correct.  (+1)  As to the OP, please read my answer again - it describes the difference between signal strength and audio level, and especially how the phone adjusts as well as  it can.  If your call stays connected then that is your proof that you have enough strength.  If you find you have to move around to find a strong enough signal then it is usually a result of your proximity to a cell tower.  Your phone will not transmit anything at all unless it hears the "I'm here" message from a cell tower.